# OAuth2 NodeJS using oauth2orizerecipes

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, oauth-2.0

I am using https://github.com/FrankHassanabad/Oauth2orizeRecipes to make an authentication server for a cordova movile app.

I have read the past few days a lot about OAuth2, and went a lot of times through what Frank Hassanabad has done there, and I tried to establish a workflow for my application.

But, alas, I am giving up and asking you guys because it seems I am stuck.

My main idea is that I want each Client (APP downloaded from the X Store) to create a new client on the auth server. This is, as far as I can think it is correct.

We have 2 kinds of workflows:

**1. New Account**

in the application I am accessing the server's new account page and make a new account, **at this phase I have to create a new accepted Client on the server**, the application is automatically created when we access the NEW ACCOUNT PAGE and the details to the app are pushed outside of the server iframe with postMessage so we can save them inside my application.

From now on, when/if something expires and no refresh token is given, the user can log in again by making an auth string like described here https://github.com/FrankHassanabad/Oauth2orizeRecipes/wiki/Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials, that when combined with the user and password, will return us a valid token and a refresh token.

All is nice and dandy, on the client I am calculating in how much time the token will expire and if the user has accessed the application after the token has expired we will send the refresh token to get new ones.

**2. Login from a different device**

This is where I am in the dark, I have to idea to make/think this workflow, for access/auth we would need a set of clientID and clientSecret, but we don't have those, so that the user can log in with his own account.

I am truly lost :)

The purpose for all this is for the user to have a management tab where he can see what devices/clients have accessed the application and with revocation rights.

I am starting to question if the authentication model in by itself is the good one :), thinking about this so much I realized that this is a sound workflow for having a server side application, which you access there, and there you have the management and from there you can allow new devices with generated clientID and secret copied into your OTHER device you want to log in with.

total blur

Comment: OR, maybe for the login process from another device, I could still open the login page from the server in an iframe, and if there is no clientID and clientSecret on the device, the server will generate new ones for the user I logged in with and pass them to the app ?

Comment: Like this, in a custom serverside management interface I could give access to the user to revoke the rights to any connected clients?